# DNN9 site expiry date

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-9

How can I edit site expiry date in a new management panel in DotNetNuke 9? There is a field in the database for it and if it's set to a date passed the site becomes unavailable, as expected. But I haven't found a field to change it in the new interface

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found it in the Persona Bar, but you can still get to the old site settings, try throwing this on the URL

/Admin/Site-Settings